# Problems with photoplethysmograph circuit diagram

Tags: operational-amplifier, voltage-divider, band-pass

I made a simple circuit of photoplethysmograph (PPG). For this I used LM358 operational amplifiers, red LED, and photodiode from old PPG. In the circuit there is band-pass filter (from calculations, frequencies from 0.4 to 22 Hz will be passed). Also, there is voltage divider in circuit to ensure bipolar voltage at the v_out reading. The problem is that reading doesn’t show any useful output when I want to see a person’s heartbeat - in oscilloscope there is just some noise near 0-volt level.

I think there may be some fundamental problem with the circuit itself. Can anyone help?
[image]

Comment: As you're debugging, lose the filters, the 150 ohm resistor  (which may well be your problem), and the 10microfarad cap on the photodiode

Comment: Yes. The 150 ohm resistor for the photosensor is much, much too low.  It probably needs to be 10's or 100's of kilohms.

Comment: @ Kevin -- you don't need a resistor there at all.

Answer (score 0):

An Instructable (https://www.instructables.com/Photoplethysmography-IR-Heart-Rate-Monitor/) that might or might not work uses much better opamps (two TL072s) than the noisy old LM358 and have a total gain of 2100 times. The LED is driven with a massive current of 100mA.The 5V supply used is too low for TL072 opamps.

Another circuit from Embedded Labs uses a dual Cmos opamp with a total gain of 10000.

Your circuit uses one noisy low input impedance LM358 with a total gain of only 85 times.
Your LED uses only 20mA.

Comment: This isn't a voltage amplifier, or at least shouldn't be.  It's a transimpedance amplifier, and the current sank through the photodiode is multiplied by 3.3 million at DC (or would be if the 150ohm resistor wasn't there.

Answer (score 0):

That 150 ohm resistor on your photodiode going to rail doesn't look correct.  The method if generating an output voltage from the current generated by the photodiode is called transimpedance amplification, and it depends on all the current going through the photodiode being sucked through the feedback path on the op amp.  You provide an easier path for the photodiode current.

Connect your photodiode directly between the inverting input and ground.  Lose all the other hardware around there: the 150 ohm resistor, the 33kohm resistor, and the capacitor.